# Analytics e-commerce tracking not tracking anything

Tags: google-analytics

I'm building a custom webshop on Laravel and i started on an e-commerce tracking plugin.
According to me, it should work, but it doesn't. Could someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Here's my code on the thankyou page:

in the head section:

```
            <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-1443260-52', 'auto');
      ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
```

And further down the page:

```
<script>

ga('require', 'ecommerce');

ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
  'id': '133',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
  'affiliation': 'Demo store 1',   // Affiliation or store name.
  'revenue': '40.00',               // Grand Total.
  'shipping': '15.00',                  // Shipping.
  'tax': '4.34'                     // Tax.
});



ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
  'id'       : '133',                  // Transaction ID. Required.
  'name'     : 'Test product',                // Product name. Required.
  'sku'      : '12',           // SKU/code.
  'category' : 'Kleur - Rood | Maat - 28inch',  // Category or variation.
  'price'    : '25.00',// Unit price.
  'quantity' : '1',                      // Quantity.
  'currency' : 'EUR'
});


ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>
```

I have enabled e-commerce tracking in Analytics, and pageviews are registered

Comment: have you waited 24 hours to check the standard reports?

Comment: Yes i've waited at least 24 hours ;)

Comment: Quite odd, i tried it yesterday and the day before, but it didn't work. Did a test order this morning and that one is now showing up in analytics. I've done a few more tests and now waiting for them to show up.

Comment: it takes time for data to show up in the standard reports.   I have seen it show up in as little as 4 hours but not be actuate its best to wait 24 hours.

Comment: Thanks for your information, please post it as answer so i can accept it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call looks fine to me.  There are a few things you should be aware of.

1. Newly created Analytics accounts can take 48 -72 hours to start showing data.
2. The standard reports of which ecommerce is one, can take 24 hours to display data.   While I have seen them display data in 4 hours this is not always the case and the data is not normally very actuate.